# It takes too long to run the matlab code for the perceptron algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network, perceptron

I am new to MATLAB and learning MATLAB to solve an assignment problem. The code is running for a long time and I am not getting any result.

This is my code:

```
bias=zeros(10,1)

y=zeros(10,1);
error_data=zeros(10,10);

for j=1:15
    for i=1:10        
        y(i,1)=hardlim(w(1:j,i).'*data.input_data(1:j,i)+bias(i));
        for k=1:10
             error_data(k,i)=data.output_data(k,i)-y(k,1);
             while error_data(k,i)~=0
             if error_data(k,i) > 0
                 w(1:j,i)=w(1:j,i)+data.input_data(1:j,i);
             elseif error_data(k,i) < 0
                 w(1:j,i)=w(1:j,i)-data.input_data(1:j,i);
             
             end
                  \end
            end    
        end
    end
```

need help

size:
data.input_data=15x10
data.output_data=10x10

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of error_data? I'm assuming it never drops exactly to zero, and so the code is stuck in an infinite while loop.

Comment: yes, you are right, one of the value remains -1 for a long time, will have to check for that

Comment: 0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Comment: If these are floating point values, they will never be zero. You want to have some tolerance, i.e. error_data<small_value

Comment: Thank you, I tried that method and got an output, but error_data isn't all 0. Will try to look for the solution.

Comment: Why don't you use the matrix multiplication capabilities for matlab?

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to to execute it before the deadline.. Had a problem with the algorithm that's why it was not converging.. Finally managed to correct it